# Google Charts, unable to plot graph

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am trying to read data from a file and display the data on a Google Coloumn Chart, however I am unable see the plots.

Global Variables

```
var tslist = new Array(); 
var iclist = new Array();
```

In function1, I am obtaining the data to be displayed

```
function function1()
{
var url="results.php";
var newcon=new XMLHttpRequest();
var temp;
newcon.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (newcon.readyState==4 && newcon.status==200)
    {
        temp=$.parseJSON(newcon.responseText);
        for(i=0;i<temp.length-1;i++)
        {
        var data=temp[i].split(' ');
        link.push(data[0]);
        tslist.push(data[1]);
        iclist.push(data[2]);
        prlist.push(data[3]);
        }
        drawVisualization(); //to draw the graph
    }
}
newcon.send();  
}
```

In drawVisualization function i am drawing the graph

```
function drawVisualization() 
{
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var numRows = link.length;
data.addColumn('string', 'UNo.');
data.addColumn('number', 'Data1');
data.addColumn('number','Data2');

    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    data.addRow([i.toString(),parseInt(iclist[i],10),parseInt(tslist[i],10)]);

new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart')).
draw(data,{title:"Comparison",hAxis: {title: "Serial"}});
}
```

On the html page i am including the following

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">    
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
 </script>
```

Can anyone point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the JSON returned by results.php?. Also, these lines doesn't look good: "for(i=0;i<temp.length-1;i++)" and "for(i=0;i<2;i++)"

Comment: the JSON returned is of the form
["Variable1 0.0035119381207293827 '89' 89.0351193812073", "Variable2 0.004451193812073 '60' 59.04451193812073"] etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here...

To start with if you are going to use global arrays, you need to declare them. link and prlist are undeclared so cause errors...

Then your starting array:

```
var example =   [
                 "Variable1 0.0035119381207293827 '89' 89.0351193812073", 
                 "Variable2 0.004451193812073 '60' 59.04451193812073"
                ];
```

=>

```
link[0] = "Variable1"
tslist[0] = "0.0035119381207293827"
iclist[0] = "'89'"
prlist[0] = "89.0351193812073"
```

OK... I think I see what you're getting at

Now the drawVis function

First the loop...

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
```

You really just want to compare the first two sets returned?

Then, what looks like the main cause of your issues

```
data.addRow([i.toString(),parseInt(iclist[i],10),parseInt(tslist[i],10)]);
```

Two problems here

```
parseInt(iclist[i],10)
```

Remember, iclist[0] = "'89'". So that fails and returns NaN due to the single quotes. You need to get rid of them

```
.replace(/\'/g, ""));
```

Would do it.

Then there's

```
parseInt(tslist[i],10)
```

We know that

```
tslist[0] = "0.0035119381207293827"
```

So I'm not sure what you're trying to visualise here as casting this to int is only ever going to give you a BFZ (big fat zero).

Maybe if you provide some more details about what you want to see from this data we can help more.

In the meantime, there's a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kentcoast/n4QTD/6/) to play with.

Comment: I realized that the value of tslist is too small to be plotted and so wasnt able to visualize it. You are bang on the target regarding the iclist and single quotes thank you for pointing it out!! Cheers!